# Import Excel Data into Powershell from SharePoint

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint

I use a lot the **ImportExcel** module in **PowerShell** and it works great with local and locally synced files. I have few Teams/SharePoint library syncing with my OneDrive and I use something on these lines to import excel data and then manipulate them directly in PowerShell (paths, file names and links are fictitious):

```
$File    = "C:\Users\Username\OneDriveFolder\File.xlsm"
$Sheet   = "Sheet1" 
$DataSet = Import-Excel -Path $File -WorkSheetname $Sheet -DataOnly -StartRow 2
$Data    = "Example"
$Query   =  $DataSet.Where({$_.$Data -like $Data})
```

I was wondering if it is was possible to use a **SharePoint URL** instead of a local path for the **-Path** attribute since I would like to import data from an Excel that is located on a SharePoint but it is not synced to my OneDrive:

```
$File    = "https://companygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/sitefolders/File.xlsm"
$Sheet   = "Sheet1" 
$DataSet = Import-Excel -Path $File -WorkSheetname $Sheet -DataOnly -StartRow 2
$Data    = "Example"
$Query   =  $DataSet.Where({$_.$Data -like $Data})
```

If I try to do that, I get a file not found error:

```
'https://companygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/sitefolders/File.xlsm' file not found
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.4.1\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:118 char:21
+                     throw "'$($Path)' file not found"
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: ('https://company... file not found:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 'https://companygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/sitefolders/File.xlsm' file not found
```

Is there a way to use the **ImportExcel** module like that? If it only works with local/locally synced files, is there an alternative to do what I would like to do?

Thanks

Comment: My advice would be to look at using the Microsoft Graph API to download the Excel file. If the Excel file is unprotected and open to the public, you might be able to download without the Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but that won't do since I wrote a script that has to run several actions at once through a foreach clause. Downloading the file locally it is not really efficient. I can already download it locally but I do not want to download it every time there we update something. Also, when syncing it via OneDrive, changes take few minutes to sync. I really need a way to work on the file as it is on the SharePoint. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find the way thanks to a page that talked about something similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/741691/how-to-load-and-read-excel-file-hosted-in-sharepoi.html

You just need to type the link as if it were a local path, for instance:

```
$File    = "\\companygroup.sharepoint.com\sites\siteFolders\File.xlsm"
$Sheet   = "Sheet1" 
$DataSet = Import-Excel -Path $File -WorkSheetname $Sheet -DataOnly -StartRow 2
$Data    = "Example"
$Query   =  $DataSet.Where({$_.$Data -like $Data})
```